# Recent 4 & Upcoming 4 birthdays

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

My table "birthdays" consists of friends birthday like

```
1990-11-13
1990-11-17
1990-11-19
1990-11-21
1990-11-21
```

etc where all the years are dummy. I tried to display birthday of friends like recently list and upcoming with this query's.

```
select concat(fname,' - ',date_format(dob,'%D %b')) as 'birthday' 
FROM birthdays 
where MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) 
  and day(dob) between day(sysdate()) and day(sysdate())+10 
order by dob ;
```

This displays only birthdays of current month only.

```
select concat(fname,' on ',date_format(dob,'%D %b')) as 'birthday' 
FROM birthdays 
where MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) 
  and day(dob) between day(sysdate())-8 and day(sysdate())-1 
order by dob ;
```

This displays recent birthday.

What I actually want is suppose If I run a query at the end of the month it should display recent 3 birthday and next month birthday.
Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following..

```
Select * from birthdays where (MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) and day(dob) 
in (select day(dob) from birthdays where DAY(dob) BETWEEN DAY(SYSDATE())-8 
AND DAY(SYSDATE())-1 ORDER BY dob limit 3) ) or month(dob) = month(now())+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this using a timestamp, I believe it would work if you use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function rather than what you are currently using. You can then subtract the number of seconds you want to be measuring.

```
select concat(fname,' on ',date_format(dob,'%D %b')) as 'birthday' 
FROM birthdays 
where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dob) between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()-(8*60*60*24)) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()+(10*60*60*24))
order by dob ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer smcjones, i tried your query and it returned 0 rows when executed.

Comment: If you only use SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dob) FROM birthdays, what do you get?

Comment: output :
658953000
645388200
636489000
660076200
633033000 etc like this i got .

Comment: The code worked fine for me. My code can be tested for correctness by running something like: `SELECT dob, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dob), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - 8*60*60*24)) AS eightdaysago, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 8*60*60*24)) AS eightdaysfromnow LIMIT 1,20;` That should be able to determine whether it has to do with what you're pulling from SELECT or even if it's just nothing in your range.